# How to set environment variables in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a docker-compose file in which I use `env_file` to read  and set a bunch of env variables at run time. These env variables are required for a command that I need to run at run time using `command`. However it looks like the `command` section is executed before the env variables are set at run time and this cause an error. How can I ensure that setting the env variables occur before executing the `command` section in a docker-compose?

Here is my docker-compose file

```
services:
  mlx-python-hdfs:
    image: image_name
    container_name: cname
    env_file: ./variables.txt
    command:
         - microservice $VAR1 $VAR2
```

`$VAR1` and `$VAR2` are read from variables.txt file but when I start the container it complains on "microservice $VAR1 $VAR2" line and show the `$VAR1` and `VAR2` as empty.

Comment: Could you share your docker-compose / env file? And what makes you think the env is set after your command IMHO such a feature would make no sense, so that would be a bug most likely.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my original post  wil my dockr-compose file. Please have a look.

Comment: @H.Z. which version docker-compose you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename your file to `.env` (without name) so `mv variables.txt .env`

edit your `compose` :

```
services:
  mlx-python-hdfs:
    image: image_name
    container_name: cname
    command:
         - microservice $VAR1 $VAR2
```

then run it normally
see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)

Answer (score 1):

The Docker Compose [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) directive has two forms.  If you specify it as a list, it is read as a list of explicit individual arguments; no shell is invoked over it, and there is no argument expansion.

```
command:
  - /bin/ls
  - -l
  - /app
```

If you specify it as a simple string, it is implicitly wrapped in `sh -c '...'`, and that shell will do variable expansion, which is what you want in your case.

```
command: microservice $VAR1 $VAR2
```

(Your form is not only not doing variable expansion, but because you specified the command in a single list item, it is looking for a file literally named `microservice $VAR1 $VAR2`, spaces and dollar signs included, to be the main container process.)

Comment: So I didn't quite get how you want me to change my command, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Make it one line, and remove the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are most likely being set inside the container. However, the `$` syntax is expanded by the compose file parser to inject settings from your shell on the host. To expand them inside the container, you need to escape them with the `$$` syntax:

```
services:
  mlx-python-hdfs:
    image: image_name
    container_name: cname
    env_file: ./variables.txt
    command:
         - microservice $$VAR1 $$VAR2
```

That will pass a literal `$` into the container which will be expanded by a shell inside the container.

See the compose file documentation for more details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Note that renaming the file to `.env` results in the variables being set inside docker-compose itself, not inside your container. That will also work if you do not escape your variables.